# How to append value into list every second without using time.sleep()?

Tags: python, pynput

```
global keys_pressed
keys_pressed = []
how_long_moved=[]
def keylogger():
    keys = [KeyCode.from_char(letter) for letter in 'wasd']
    def on_press(key):
        start=time.time()
        if key in keys:
            print(f'good key {key}')
        else: print(f'bad key {key}')
    def on_release(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            return False

    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

I have the code above for a keylogger that logs every 'w a s d' key as a good key. Is it possible to append a random letter into the list `how_long_moved` for every 1 second a key is pressed without using `time.sleep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use non-block thread.And use `time.time()` to check the time:

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode, Key, Controller, Listener
import string, random

global keys_pressed
keys_pressed = []
how_long_moved=[]
def keylogger():
    keys = [KeyCode.from_char(letter) for letter in 'wasd']
    def on_press(key):
        if key in keys:
            print(f'good key {key}')
        else: print(f'bad key {key}')
    def on_release(key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            return False

    listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()

    start_time = time.time()
    controller = Controller()
    all_str = string.ascii_lowercase
    while True:
        if time.time() - start_time >= 1:
            start_time = time.time()
            random_pressed_key = random.choice(all_str)
            controller.press(random_pressed_key)
            how_long_moved.append(random_pressed_key)
            print(how_long_moved)

keylogger()
```

Example output:

```
['d']
good key 'd'
bad key 'g'
['d', 'g']
good key 's'
['d', 'g', 's']
bad key 'b'
['d', 'g', 's', 'b']
```

---

Due to there are two threads, so the order of output is irregular(the `how_long_moved` and `bad key or good key`).